# Как исправить ошибку проверки цепочки сертификата в WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

Пытаюсь реализовать простейшую аутентификацию в WCF службе с использованием логина/пароля.

Конфиг:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
    </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TestAuthWCF.SecretServiceBinding">
          <!-- Укажем Security Mode -->
          <security mode="Message">
            <!-- Тип аутентификации -->
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="TestAuthWCF.SecretServiceBehavior"
        name="TestAuthWCF.TestAuthWCF">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/service" binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="TestAuthWCF.SecretServiceBinding" contract="TestAuthWCF.ITestAuthWCF" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/service" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TestAuthWCF.SecretServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="Фамилия Имя Отчество" storeLocation="CurrentUser"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
              customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="TestAuthWCF.CustomUserNameValidator, TestAuthWCF" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Реализация Валидатора:

```
public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            // Доступ разрешен только пользователю "ilya" по паролю "pass"
            if (!(userName == "ilya" && password == "pass"))
            {
                throw new FaultException("Неверный логин или пароль");
            }
        }
    }
```

В итоге получаю ошибку следующего плана
[image: Ошибка]

Сертификат получен в УФК, действующий. Корневые сертификаты так же установлены. Просьба подсказать в какую сторону копать, второй день парюсь с данной ошибкой.
Заранее благодарен.

UPD1 (Информация о сертификате):

```
Сертификат X509:
Версия: 3
Серийный номер: 60bfae9609eec54c8279580e7b8c0dc3ea3f46b6
Алгоритм подписи:
    ObjectID алгоритма: 1.2.643.2.2.3 ГОСТ Р 34.11/34.10-2001
    Параметры алгоритма: NULL
Поставщик:
    CN=Федеральное казначейство
    O=Федеральное казначейство
    C=RU
    L=Москва
    STREET=улица Ильинка, дом 7
    ОГРН=1047797019830
    ИНН=007710568760
    S=г. Москва
    E=uc_fk@roskazna.ru

 NotBefore: 25.12.2017 9:35
 NotAfter: 25.03.2019 9:35

Субъект:
    CN=<Удалено>
    SN=<Удалено>
    G=<Удалено>
    O=<Удалено>
    L=<Удалено>
    S=<Удалено>
    C=RU
    E=<Удалено>
    СНИЛС=<Удалено>
    ИНН=<Удалено>

Алгоритм открытого ключа:
    ObjectID алгоритма: 1.2.643.2.2.19 ГОСТ Р 34.10-2001
    Параметры алгоритма:
    0000  30 12 06 07 2a 85 03 02  02 24 00 06 07 2a 85 03
    0010  02 02 1e 01
        1.2.643.2.2.36.0 ГОСТ Р 34.10-2001, параметры обмена по умолчанию
        1.2.643.2.2.30.1 ГОСТ Р 34.11-94, параметры по умолчанию
Длина открытого ключа: 512 бит
Открытый ключ: UnusedBits = 0
    0000  04 40 18 8f e3 11 07 31  e7 0f f7 c0 85 dc 4c 0c
    0010  cc 1e e1 17 b6 8f 66 fd  ff f5 03 58 93 ef fb 6e
    0020  ce b6 c6 b8 95 fe da 92  7d 8f 73 09 b3 07 06 c8
    0030  79 93 ea 6c c7 28 2b de  7c 52 2b b1 b8 86 ce 36
    0040  d5 aa
Расширения сертификатов: 11
    2.5.29.19: Флаги = 1(Критический), Длина = 2
    Основные ограничения
        Тип субъекта=Конечный субъект
        Ограничение на длину пути=Отсутствует

    2.5.29.32: Флаги = 0, Длина = 16
    Политики сертификата
        [1]Политика сертификата:
             Идентификатор политики=Класс средства ЭП КС1
        [2]Политика сертификата:
             Идентификатор политики=Класс средства ЭП КС2

    2.5.29.17: Флаги = 0, Длина = 1a
    Дополнительное имя субъекта
        Другое имя:
             T=13 0a 31 32 31 39 31 30 32 36 35 36
        URL=0

    1.2.643.100.111: Флаги = 0, Длина = 2d
    Средство электронной подписи владельца
        Средство электронной подписи: "КриптоПро CSP" (версия 3.6)
    1.2.643.100.112: Флаги = 0, Длина = 126
    Средства электронной подписи и УЦ издателя
        Средство электронной подписи: "КриптоПро CSP" (версия 3.6) (исполнение 2
)
        Заключение на средство ЭП: № 149/7/6-293 от 26.06.2017
        Средство УЦ: "Программно-аппаратный комплекс "Юнисерт-ГОСТ". Версия 2.1"

        Заключение на средство УЦ: Сертификат соответствия № СФ/128-2878 от 20.0
6.2016
    2.5.29.15: Флаги = 1(Критический), Длина = 4
    Использование ключа
        Цифровая подпись, Неотрекаемость, Шифрование ключей, Согласование ключей
 (e8)

    2.5.29.37: Флаги = 0, Длина = 14
    Улучшенный ключ
        Проверка подлинности клиента (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
        Неизвестное использование ключа (1.2.643.100.2.1)

    2.5.29.16: Флаги = 0, Длина = 24
    Период использования закрытого ключа
        Действителен с 25 декабря 2017 г. 9:35:52
        Действителен по 25 марта 2019 г. 9:35:52
    2.5.29.35: Флаги = 0, Длина = 17c
    Идентификатор ключа центра сертификатов
        Идентификатор ключа=16 55 91 a6 51 58 c4 89 2c 6b 51 5b d2 85 19 0a 01 4
4 48 22
        Поставщик сертификата:
             Адрес каталога:
                  CN=Головной удостоверяющий центр
                  ИНН=007710474375
                  ОГРН=1047702026701
                  O=Минкомсвязь России
                  STREET="125375 г. Москва, ул. Тверская, д. 7"
                  L=Москва
                  S=77 г. Москва
                  C=RU
                  E=dit@minsvyaz.ru
        Серийный номер сертификата=36 ac d4 55 00 00 00 00 01 2f

    2.5.29.31: Флаги = 0, Длина = 57
    Точки распространения списков отзыва (CRL)
        [1]Точка распределения списка отзыва (CRL)
             Имя точки распространения:
                  Полное имя:
                       URL=http://crl.roskazna.ru/crl/ucfk.crl
        [2]Точка распределения списка отзыва (CRL)
             Имя точки распространения:
                  Полное имя:
                       URL=http://crl.fsfk.local/crl/ucfk.crl

    2.5.29.14: Флаги = 0, Длина = 16
    Идентификатор ключа субъекта
        f6 91 76 00 0d 6f d3 38 79 8f 39 6d 17 a0 90 fb 6e 09 79 4c

Алгоритм подписи:
    ObjectID алгоритма: 1.2.643.2.2.3 ГОСТ Р 34.11/34.10-2001
    Параметры алгоритма: NULL
Подпись: НеиспользБит=0
    0000  9b fb 03 a6 7a 44 1f 72  50 4a 12 83 21 14 31 58
    0010  18 7b 70 4f 4f f4 50 fa  73 7d 13 a8 34 9a ca 2c
    0020  11 4c 76 e0 e9 82 24 99  3e 84 c9 0e e0 34 53 40
    0030  d9 95 34 a8 aa 57 88 0f  99 31 f3 74 05 a4 1f c3
Не корневой сертификат
Хеш ИД ключа (rfc-sha1): f6 91 76 00 0d 6f d3 38 79 8f 39 6d 17 a0 90 fb 6e 09 7
9 4c
Хеш ИД ключа (sha1): 9e 7c 56 3e 09 21 71 d7 86 16 06 dd 2b 4f 99 bd ac 17 74 1e

Хеш сертификата(md5): df 40 62 65 de 0e 67 7e 22 f8 a5 d6 cc 9d ed 48
Хеш сертификата(sha1): c3 e2 bf cf fc e6 91 13 f0 ac 76 93 b2 23 a0 7d 03 2e d7
64
```

Comment: Покажите вывод команды `certutil -dump "Путь к файлу .cer для сертификата"`, вырезав личную информацию (если она там есть).

Comment: Добавил в тему.

Comment: У вас сертификат задан для сервера, а в данных сертификата OID "Проверка подлинности клиента". Случаем не в этом проблема?

Comment: Несколько вопросов: 1. Клиента запускаете на той же машине? 2. Что показывает Windows для этого сертификата на клиентской машине если она отличается от серверной?

Comment: @IgorLabutin, Клиент и сервер запускается с одной машины.

Comment: Тогда проверьте что корневые сертификаты установлены правильно (т.е. и сервис и клиент их видят). Не забудьте что есть Trusted Root для пользователя, а есть для компьютера и если сервис запущен именно как служба Windows, то она смотрит в computer trusted root